# Facebook Pixel/CAPI custom event deduplication

Tags: facebook, duplicates, pixel

I'm trying to implement a custom event with Facebook Pixel and Facebook Conversion API, but I have a problem with the deduplication process.

I read in the documentation that:

> We determine if events are identical based on their ID and name. So,
> for an event to be deduplicated:
>
> In corresponding events, a Facebook pixel's eventID must match the conversion API's event_id.
> In corresponding events, a Facebook pixel's event must match the
> conversion API's event_name.

I set correctly the event name and id in both cases (pixel and conversion api) but it's not working 100%. Sometimes my events are deduplicated, and sometimes not.

Here is a screenshot to understand better:
[Test events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgFA1.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue :(